# Very odd gas furnace installation in apartment... How do I change the filter?

Tags: hvac, heating, furnace, natural-gas, filter

Here are some pictures of the installation: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5x7W.jpg

[image]

This furnace is actually in my unit. It looks like the previous tenant or landlord just jammed a bunch of filters on both sides. I find it hard to believe that this is the right installation but can't really figure out how a filter should be properly installed? Has anyone seen anything like this? Or was the whole furnace just not installed right to begin with. Seems very weird. The 4th and 5th pictures are what is on the opposite side of the furnace.

Comment: Is there no filter slot outside the furnace housing and built into the intake duct plenum? Is that the output port at the top of the one photo? It's not clear what the overall setup is from your photos.

Comment: If you move the filters on the right side of the photo, is there a hole in the furnace cabinet? Or is the only opening in the "back" (opposite the photo)?

Comment: The only opening is on the back of the furnace. I do not see any filter slot whatsoever.

Comment: Usually there's a filter installed on the return air duct, but since this unit doesn't have a return air duct (only a return air hole). They've simply placed filters on each side of the blower. This might work, but it's not an ideal solution.

Comment: Unrelated, but if it's in your living space, I'd make sure you have a carbon monoxide detector installed. Landlord is likely responsible for doing so.

Comment: I'd guess those filters are just stored there. Or at least not doing anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell for sure, but it appears that the return air intake is on the "back" of the furnace.

[image]

You'll have to measure the opening, and then buy a return air grill that can accommodate a filter.

[image]

You may have to install a bit of ducting, or seal the grill to the furnace using some foil tape or mastic. You'll want the return air to all be pulled through the filter, so you want the grill sealed to the furnace cabinet.

Once it's installed, you'll just have to pop open the grill to replace the filter.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like it could be the best possible solution. I would assume that this is the return air vent yes, I don't see one anywhere else in the apartment.

Comment: Do I need ducting for this to be effective? I can't just replace this grille with one of that allows for a filter? If I do need to install ducting, how and where am I installing it? I am not very experienced in HVAC.

Comment: @Karmapolice if the grill is deep enough that you can seal it to the furnace, then you don't need a duct.  Otherwise you need a duct to bridge the gap from the grill to the furnace.